# using ssh agent forwarding to clone git repo

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a private github repo that I want to clone in an EC2 instance. From my local computer, I access to it via private key (so I can clone, pull, push only using my keys, and not passwords).
I don't want to store my keys on the EC2 instance, since I will not be the only one accesing it.
I am trying to do this using ssg-agent forwarding.
I have added my keys to the agent in my local computer, then logged into the EC2 instance using:

```
ssh -A ec2-user@instanceip
```

but when I try to do a git clone, it will still prompt me for username and password.
I already changed the ssh config in the ec2 instance to allow agent forwarding, and my keys are already added to the agent.

Comment: Has the ssh key been added to the agent? Use `ssh-add -l` to list all the keys the agent knows about.

Comment: Yes I did add them to the agent, I edited the question so it's more clear.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same / a similar problem and solved it like this...

Before, the problem was like this:

On my own computer, `ssh-add -l` gave:

```
2048 <fingerprint> (RSA)
```

Then, if I did `ssh -A my-server` and ran `ssh-add -l` I got:

```
2048 <fingerprint> (RSA)
```

as expected.

But, when I did `ssh -A some-supercomputer` (not mine) and ran `ssh-add -l` I got:

```
The agent has no identities.
```

Turns out the problem was I had the following line in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

which I had put there to start an agent because that machine did not start one by default. Removing that line from my `~/.bashrc` allowed `ssh-add -l` on that machine to give `2048 <fingerprint> (RSA)` as expected.

Now, I doubt you have that line in your `~/.bashrc` but the point is: that line was starting a new agent that overrode the forwarded agent. So, if you are looking at the same outputs from `ssh-add -l`, it may be that the remote system is somehow starting a new agent that is overriding your forwarded agent. I'm not sure how to check that explicitly, nor how to fix it if you are not a system admin.

Alternatively, I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/168933/extra-configuration-required-for-ssh-agent-forwarding) which notes that the `AllowAgentForwarding` option needs to be enabled on the remote machine's `sshd_config` - again, tricky to solve if you don't have admin rights.

Answer (score 3):

You must use the `ssh` **url address** of your repository instead of `https` one in `.git/config`:

Change:

```ini
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/MYUSER/MYREPO.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

to:

```ini
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:MYUSER/MYREPO.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

You can also set `fetch` and `push` urls separately, so that you can fetch without the need for your keys, but use them for pushing:

```ini
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/MYUSER/MYREPO.git
    pushurl = git@github.com:MYUSER/MYREPO.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

*Side note:*
The `https` url will always ask you for your github credentials to `push` (which since recently won't even work, as they turned off that authorization).
In that case you can use `gh auth login` command (from *GitHub CLI*) as an alternative to using your keys.

### As for the general instructions of how to forward your keys:

Start the ssh-agent on your local machine:
`` $ eval `ssh-agent` ``
Add your private keys (change paths, here it adds all keys from `~/.ssh`):
`$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/*.pem ~/.ssh/*_rsa`
List your added keys for confirmation:
`$ ssh-add -l`
Login to the remote host:
`$ ssh -A user@host`
On the remote machine, confirm the list of your keys:
`$ ssh-add -l`

After you are done, logout and kill the ssh-agent on your local machine:
`$ ssh-agent -k`